# How to simply extract specific values of regression curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2, non-linear-regression

I would like to extract several predicted y-values for the x-values given from this graph :

[image]

I know that it is possible to get the x and y coordinates of the curve by using the following function :

```
coordinate <- ggplot_build(curve)$data[[2]][,c("x","y")]
head(coordinate,n = 6L)

#          x         y
1 0.1810660 32845.225
2 0.4810660 27635.136
3 0.7553301 23904.792
4 1.3295942 18316.923
5 1.8288582 15092.595
6 5.0312446  8018.707
```

Is there a function that allows you to directly obtain the predicted value of y for a given x value that does not appear in `coordinate` such as for example 3.5?

Comment: I don't think the model object is stored in the plot object. If you want a model to use, I'd suggest fitting a model directly, rather than trying to extract it from a ggplot.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for your answer ! I was just wondering if it was possible to do this directly via ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gregor mentions, you should fit a model aside of the plot.
Best you can do to "simply" obtain a value otherwise is an interpolating spline

```
sfun = splinefun(coordinate)

sfun(3.5)
```